# Особый алгоритм отображения ссылок (пагинация) на PHP

Tags: php, pagination

Подскажите реализацию алгоритма отображения ссылок на страницы

Во всех известных алгоритмах ссылка на текущую страницу отображается посередине:

`[20][21][22][ТЕКУЩАЯ][24][25][26]`.

При нажатии на соседние ссылки они становятся опять посередине, т.е. слева по 3 ссылки и справа по 3 ссылки.

А вот как нужно мне:

```
[20][ТЕКУЩАЯ][22][23][24][25][26]
[20][21][ТЕКУЩАЯ][23][24][25][26]
[20][21][22][ТЕКУЩАЯ][24][25][26]
[20][21][22][23][ТЕКУЩАЯ][25][26]
[20][21][22][23][24][ТЕКУЩАЯ][26]
```

Т.е. чтобы текущая страница из диапазона ссылок на примере могла плавать между `[21]` и `[25]`.
Под `[ТЕКУЩАЯ]` имеется введу отсутствие ссылок, например: `<b>[СТРАНИЦА]</b>`.

А при нажатии на крайнюю ссылку `[20]` список становится таким:

```
[15][16][17][18][19][ТЕКУЩАЯ][21]
```

При нажатии на крайнюю `[26]`:

```
[25][ТЕКУЩАЯ][27][28][29][30][31]
```

Comment: Попробуйте сначала описать сам алгоритм. Как только опишете - сможете реализовать сами или запросить помощи у сообщества.

Comment: Все же рекомендую начать с описательной части. Сформулируйте по-русски, как это должно работать. При этом, бОльшая часть вопросов по алгоритму сама собой отпадет.

Comment: Обновил описание

Comment: Вот то, что вы сейчас сделали - это изобразили картинку текстом. Поймите меня правильно, я хочу вам помочь :) 

"При первом нажатии на номер страницы она располагается посередине списка. При нажатии на следующую страницу список не двигается до тех пор, пока не нажата предпоследняя страница из списка." И так далее. Как только вы опишете *алгоритм* словами, вы тут же сможете его реализовать. Просто поверьте :)